# php multidimensional array diff with multi conditions

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array in php:

```
$all_users = [
    0=[
        user_id = 1,
        team_id = 1,
    ],
    1=[
        user_id = 1,
        team_id = 2,
    ],
    2=[
        user_id = 2,
        team_id = 1,
    ],
    3=[
        user_id = 3,
        team_id = 1,
    ],
];
```

```
$selected_users = [
    0=[
        user_id = 1,
        team_id = 1,
    ],
    1=[
        user_id = 3,
        team_id = 1,
    ],
];
```

I want to return not-selected users. I mean that I want:

```
$not_selected_users = [
    0=[
        user_id = 1,
        team_id = 2,
    ],
    1=[
        user_id = 2,
        team_id = 1,
    ],
];
```

How I can get this?

It is a multidimensional array with multi conditions. I test with multiple for, array_search, array_keys but I can't get it.

**Notice:** In all_users `user_id` can be repeatable and for example each user can be in multi teams or other... I mean we can have repeated user_id in all_users array.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can do this by comparing values from one array with values of another.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Stack-over flow is not a free coding service you need to provide us your efforts to achieve this or if you are stuck at something. Please do your own research or provide a minimal example of your work.
[Click here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) to know how much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask good questions.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to know what types of questions to avoid asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
// To speed up search you need `user_id` values as keys:
$selected_users_keys = array_column($selected_users, 'user_id', 'user_id');
// next just filter:
$not_selected_users = array_filter(
    $all_users,
    function ($v) use ($selected_users_keys) { 
        return !isset($selected_users_keys[$v['user_id']]); 
    }
);
```

[The fiddle](https://3v4l.org/k2BOD).

Modified algorithm [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/cgPeM):

```
$selected_users_keys = [];
foreach ($selected_users as $user) {
    $selected_users_keys[$user['user_id'] . '-' . $user['team_id']] = 1;
}

// next just filter:
$not_selected_users = array_filter(
    $all_users,
    function ($v) use ($selected_users_keys) { 
        return !isset($selected_users_keys[$v['user_id'] . '-' . $v['team_id']]); 
    }
);

print_r($not_selected_users);
```

Comment: sorry, I update my question. I have a team_id too. in all_users user_id is not unique and it can be repeat.

Comment: So modify algorithm so as key become something like `user_id:team_id` and filter.

Comment: thanks but team_id is an example that you can understand my concept and my problem. we should only use user_id. and user_id can be repeat in other arrays properties. my problem is complex and I simplify it by this simple example.

Comment: for example It possible that a user not assigened to any team! then he don't have team_id

Comment: I'm not going to solve all edge cases of your problem. I showed you a direction. You either follow it and modify the answer to fit your needs or not follow. Over.

Comment: Yes i think the answer should be accepted the answer is perfect.